# Uncaught Invariant Violation: Function components cannot have refs. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need ref to focus when my content gets loaded but its giving issue. Could pls tell whats the issue with this code. For functional component

```
const Boost = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    Boost.current.focus();
  });
return (
      <h1 id="keepYourPlan" ref="Boost" tabIndex="-1">
        Milan
      </h1>
);
```

Comment: Change `ref="Boost"` to `ref={Boost}`.

Answer (score 0):

useEffect is not an ideal way to determine if your component has loaded. Your ref could be null, plus your side-effect will run on every render. I would suggest to use ref callbacks instead:

```
const focusOnMount = (node) => node?.focus();

return (
      <h1 id="keepYourPlan" ref={focusOnMount} tabIndex="-1">
        Milan
      </h1>
);
```

You can read more about callback refs here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

If you're passing the ref or refCallback to your own custom component instead of h1 here, the custom component will need to be wrapped in forwardRef if its a functional component. More about ref forwarding here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html